# DATA LOAD INFILE - using a Text Editor

Tags: mysql, csv, text-editor, load-data-infile

I'm doing a simple CSV import to MySQL via DATA LOAD INFILE. I have lots of strings with commas inside, and the CSV file is saving these strings with double quotes around them; e.g.

```
"The Good\, The Bad & The Queen"
```

I am using `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`but, if I have edited the CSV file at all using TextEdit (Mac) and thus saving the file again, then the result in MySQL is:

```
â€œThe Good, The Bad & The Queenâ€
```

How can I stop this occurring please? Can anyone recommend a Text Editor (or something) that wouldn't cause this sort of thing, unlike TextEdit?

Cheers  :o)

Comment: Looks like you have to either set the right charset in the text editor or specify it in your DATA LOAD INFIOLE statement. 

    'LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' CHARACTER SET charset_name OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY 'char' …

(taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I'm missing the point but I don't want a special character set...I just don't want my Text Editor to bugger about with what's in the file! TextWrangler seems to be doing the trick.